# Does MonkeyTalk supports Long hold to reorder cells in TableView

Tags: testing, gesture, monkeytalk

MonkeyTalk is recording the events,but while playing back it's not recognizing the UI elements and cannot play back.
Is it possible to test the Gesture based feature i.e Long hold to reorder cells using MonkeyTalk in iOS application. The link to that application is
https://github.com/mystcolor/jtgesturebasedtableviewdemo.

So Kindly provide me the information whether we can use MonkeyTalk tool to test the application having this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In monkeytalk you can use command

*LongSelectIndex(itemNumber:int)*:void ~Long press an item by index. 
"itemNumber":is the index of the item to long press.

```
Table (monkeyID) LongSelectIndex (cellIndex)
```

Here is a useful monkeytalk command reference: https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/command-reference

for your problem check under Table section.

Comment: Hello, I tried it, its recording but not playing back. I tested for the below application  https://github.com/mystcolor/jtgesturebasedtableviewdemo. Could you please check this out and reply.